# Scope of Modula-3

Tags: scope, modula-3

All,

Can anyone please tell me what scoping technique does Modula-3 employ? I found very little information on internet.

Comment: I did not find a tag 'Modula-3' and hence tagged it as Modula-2.

Comment: And yet it's a question specifically about Modula-3 so it should be tagged such, so I fixed that for you.

Comment: @pax: Thank you. As I said, there was no Modula-3 tag and neither am I allowed to create new tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [lexically scoped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_scope#Lexical_scoping), like all the [Wirthian languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niklaus_Wirth#Programming_languages). While [Modula-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modula-3) was not created by Wirth, it's scoped like [Modula-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modula-2) and [Oberon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberon_programming_language).